# Global macro variables (created with CALL SYMPUTX) won't resolve properly within SAS macro program

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm very new to coding macros in SAS, so I'm mostly looking for a push in the right direction.

I'm trying to create a big macro program, and within it I'm using `CALL SYMPUTX` to create several global macro variables that I reference within the macro program.  My code is as follows:

```
options symbolgen mlogic;
filename ALBB 'C:\[file path]\AL.csv';
libname mylibx 'C:\[file path]\ALBB';

%macro baseball(al=mylibx.al, nl=myliby.nl, var1=salary, class1=position, pd=percent_deviation);

data &al;
infile ALBB dlm=',' dsd firstobs=5 obs=381;
input team :$20. name :$20. salary :comma12. position :$20.;
run;

proc print data=&al (firstobs=1 obs=6);
format &var1 comma12.;
run;

proc means data=&al noprint;
var &var1;
class &class1;
output out=med_al median=med;
run;

data median_al;
set med_al;
if _TYPE_ = 0 then delete;
run;

****Macro Variables in question are below****
data _NULL_;
set &al;
    if &class1='Catcher' then call symputx('MedianC',med);
    if &class1='Catcher' then call symputx('FrequencyC',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='First Baseman' then call symputx('MedianFB',med);
    if &class1='First Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencyFB',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='Outfielder' then call symputx('MedianO',med);
    if &class1='Outfielder' then call symputx('FrequencyO',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='Pitcher' then call symputx('MedianP',med);
    if &class1='Pitcher' then call symputx('FrequencyP',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='Second Baseman' then call symputx('MedianSB',med);
    if &class1='Second Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencySB',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='Shortstop' then call symputx('MedianS',med);
    if &class1='Shortstop' then call symputx('FrequencyS',_FREQ_);
    if &class1='Third Baseman' then call symputx('MedianTB',med);
    if &class1='Third Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencyTB',_FREQ_);
run;

data temp;
set &al;
    if &class1='Catcher' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianC)/(&MedianC))*100;
    if &class1='First Baseman' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianFB)/(&MedianFB))*100;
    if &class1='Outfielder' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianO)/(&MedianO))*100;
    if &class1='Pitcher' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianP)/(&MedianP))*100;
    if &class1='Second Baseman' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianSB)/(&MedianSB))*100;
    if &class1='Shortstop' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianS)/(&MedianS))*100;
    if &class1='Third Baseman' then &pd=((&var1-&MedianTB)/(&MedianTB))*100;
run;

proc print data=temp (firstobs=1 obs=10);
title 'Information about Baseball Players';
footnote1 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianC, dollar12.)) &FrequencyC;
footnote2 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianFB, dollar12.)) &FrequencyFB;
footnote3 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianO, dollar12.)) &FrequencyO;
footnote4 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianP, dollar12.)) &FrequencyP;
footnote5 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianSB, dollar12.)) &FrequencySB;
footnote6 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianS, dollar12.)) &FrequencyS;
footnote7 %sysfunc(putn(&MedianTB, dollar12.)) &FrequencyTB;
run;

%mend baseball;
%baseball()
```

While I'm not sure if I'm doing any of this correctly, it's definitely clear that my `'MedianX'` and `'FrequencyX'` macro variables aren't working. They resolve to missing values (whereas outside of the macro program, they resolve correctly).

Could anyone offer some guidance? Thanks very much!

Comment: It's hard to replicate this without data. My instinct say's its the multiple if rather than if/then statements. What happens if you add a bunch of %put after the data _null_ step, do any of the macro variables resolve?

Comment: I wouldn't write the code this way.  Merge the means-produced dataset on class to the main one, then you have all these variables there.  Macro variables really aren't the place for data like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copying this into SAS shows that the data null statement line 28 is removed due to the comment on line 27 having no ending semi colon. With that adding, this works for me based on the spread sheet I made.

Also, the *null* and temp tables have set &al which is your first dataset so does not contain the med and *FREQ* variables, these should read set median_al for this to resolve correctly.

Comment: Agree, and if this is the cause, it should have been apparent from errors in the log.  When macro programming, if you have options MPRINT turned on, the log is much easier to read.

Comment: I only added in the comment to make my question clearer on here.  It wasn't in my original code.  But you're definitely right about `&al`, which was a silly mistake on my part.  Thanks for your help!